# Group by on column that repeats

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm having trouble putting this issue into words which is probably why I can't find an example so here is what I'd like to do.

I have a table like such

```
    | counter|      timestamp      |
    |   1    | 2018-01-01T11:11:01 |
    |   1    | 2018-01-01T11:11:02 |
    |   1    | 2018-01-01T11:11:03 |
    |   2    | 2018-01-01T11:11:04 |
    |   2    | 2018-01-01T11:11:05 |
    |   3    | 2018-01-01T11:11:06 |
    |   3    | 2018-01-01T11:11:07 |
    |   1    | 2018-01-01T11:11:08 |
    |   1    | 2018-01-01T11:11:09 |
    |   1    | 2018-01-01T11:11:10 |
```

what I'd like to do is group by each group of counters so if I do a query like

```
SELECT counter, MAX(timestamp) as st, MIN(timestamp) as et 
FROM table 
GROUP BY counter;
```

the result would be

```
    | counter |          st         |         et          |
    |   1     | 2018-01-01T11:11:01 | 2018-01-01T11:11:03 |
    |   2     | 2018-01-01T11:11:04 | 2018-01-01T11:11:05 |
    |   3     | 2018-01-01T11:11:06 | 2018-01-01T11:11:07 |
    |   1     | 2018-01-01T11:11:08 | 2018-01-01T11:11:10 |
```

instead of what actually happens which is

```
    | counter |          st         |         et          |
    |   1     | 2018-01-01T11:11:01 | 2018-01-01T11:11:10 |
    |   2     | 2018-01-01T11:11:04 | 2018-01-01T11:11:05 |
    |   3     | 2018-01-01T11:11:06 | 2018-01-01T11:11:07 |
```

So I'd like some what to combine group by and partition ideally without having nested queries

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: updated to to clarify @STLDeveloper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to designate groups with the same repeating values of counter. This can be done using two window functions `lag()` and cumulative `sum()`:

```
select counter, min(timestamp) as st, max(timestamp) as et
from (
    select counter, timestamp, sum(grp) over w as grp
    from (
        select *, (lag(counter, 1, 0) over w <> counter)::int as grp
        from my_table
        window w as (order by timestamp)
        ) s
    window w as (order by timestamp)
    ) s
group by counter, grp
order by st
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=026b49709f2d5dde4cf9911e45447eba)

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate a new groups:

> ```
> create table tbl(counter int, ts timestamp);
> insert into tbl values
>     (1, '2018-01-01T11:11:01'),
>     (1, '2018-01-01T11:11:02'),
>     (1, '2018-01-01T11:11:03'),
>     (2, '2018-01-01T11:11:04'),
>     (2, '2018-01-01T11:11:05'),
>     (3, '2018-01-01T11:11:06'),
>     (3, '2018-01-01T11:11:07'),
>     (1, '2018-01-01T11:11:08'),
>     (1, '2018-01-01T11:11:09'),
>     (1, '2018-01-01T11:11:10');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select min(counter) as counter, min(ts) as st, max(ts) as et
> from
> (
>     select counter, ts, sum(rst) over (order by ts) as grp
>     from 
>          (
>          select counter, ts,
>                 case when coalesce(lag(counter) over (order by ts), -1) <> counter then 1 end rst
>          from   tbl
>          ) t1
> ) t2
> group by grp
> ```
>
> ```
> counter | st                  | et                 
> ------: | :------------------ | :------------------
>       3 | 2018-01-01 11:11:06 | 2018-01-01 11:11:07
>       1 | 2018-01-01 11:11:08 | 2018-01-01 11:11:10
>       2 | 2018-01-01 11:11:04 | 2018-01-01 11:11:05
>       1 | 2018-01-01 11:11:01 | 2018-01-01 11:11:03
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3805efa8f28082db19af0cc393796b8d)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ranking* function

```
select counter, min(timestamp) st, max(timestamp) et
from (select *, 
               row_number() over (order by timestamp) Seq1,
               row_number() over (partition by counter order by timestamp) Seq2 
      from table 
     ) t
group by counter, (Seq1-Seq2);
```

This would use the differences of two ranking functions (`Seq1-Seq2`) and use them in `GROUP BY` clause.